# Tufts MAZE LabView Program Will Not Run on EV3

Tags: ev3, programming

Through the 2012 LabVIEW for LEGO software package, I found an example of a maze from Tufts.  I cannot get it to run on an EV3.  It appears to just constantly execute the initialization.

How can I attach the vi to a question?

Comment: Can you share the initialization code and show where it seems to be looping? Most of us will not have the example code you refer to.

Comment: Phil, I would like to send the vi., but how? I don't see an "attach file." Tony

Comment: You can add an image file (if you have made a screenshot - assuming this is what you mean with "vi"- visual) by clicking on the little picture icon above the editor when you click "edit" on your post. Or you can upload the image somewhere and then include it as a link like so: [Screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/UNnUeCX.png)

Answer (score 1):

LEGO MINDSTORMS EV3 was not releases until 2013, so I think it is safe to say that the software in question was designed for the NXT only and will not run on the EV3.